# How pass html code as parameter in javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass html code in javascript function.

```
<a onclick="PreviewTemplate('<p>Test{#email}</p>')">Preview</a>

function PreviewTemplate(temp) {
            debugger;
            var contents = temp;
            var mywin = window.open("", "ckeditor_preview", "location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,width=500,height=500");

            $(mywin.document.body).html(contents);
}
```

Comment: The new window doesn't load any of the ASP.NET libraries, so it won't process things like `{#email}`.

Comment: @Barmar but isn't it already processed inside the `<a>` attribute?

Comment: Good point. What do you see in the Elements tab of DevTools?

Comment: *IF* the `{#email}` is rendered correctly (you can always inspect element and see if it's there) - your code should work as expected, given you loaded correctly the jQuery library. And stop using inline JS like `onclick`. Use `Element.addEventListener()` instead. place your scripts at the bottom right before the closing `</body>` tag, and most likely you'll not run into issues that the  `PreviewTemplate` function is called before instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following code.

```
const handleOnClick = (htmlContent) => {
     `<p>Test${htmlContent}</p>`
} 

<a onclick="() => handleOnClick( " + customHtmlContent + ")">Preview</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. This code working fine when i using hard coded value but when i use object variable which contains html code this approach is not working not consider that html variable as string. like `PreviewTemplate(<p>Test{#email}</p>)` instead of `PreviewTemplate('<p>Test{#email}</p>')`

Comment: My actual code is `<a onclick="PreviewTemplate(@item.Template)">Preview</a>` and this `@item.Template` contains html code.

Comment: Glad to know that you have some progress. I have edited my answer, you can check whether it works. If it works you can give me and upvote :))